# Union query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables catelog and catelog copy. And, I need to to display both these table fields as one table using mysql.

Can anyone correct this code for joining 2 tables?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catelog WHERE title='".$fileid."'union
select status  from catelog_copy " );
```

Comment: @Lavanya, can you explain what the 2 tables look like and how you want the output to be ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here excactly?

Comment: @Lavanya: The purpose of the title of the question is to explain in few words the problem and the bigger box underneath is used to describe it in detail. It will be great to run a spell-check as well. Forming your question will help people answer it much faster.

Comment: In a UNION both sections of your query need to return the exact same fields. You may also be looking for a JOIN instead.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT` statements you'd like to `UNION` have to return the same number of columns and types of those columns should match.

So

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM table1 UNION SELECT a, b, c FROM table2
```

will work, but

```
SELECT a, b FROM table1 UNION SELECT a, b, c FROM table2
```

will not.

Names of the fields and the fields themselves might be different though.

Comment: The requirement for UNION is that the select list for each query in the UNION provides the same number of columns, and these should be of matching types.  The names for the columns in the result come from the name of the column/aliases of the first query.

Comment: @mjv, fixed :) Although it makes explanation more confusing.